# FT Search on a search page

Tags: sql-server

I have a search page that accepts nearly 20 to 30 different parameters of which more than 20 of them are full text search enabled. I was thinking of writing a stored proc with all these 30 parameters and use FT search for fields that are FTS enabled. There are a few search strings that can also be empty which I believe FTS does not handle very well.

Is there a more sleek way of meeting the requirement and not to hand code 30 different parameters in the stored proc and making sure almost half of them have FTS enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your users want to be able to perform full text searches limited to the particular field represented by your 20-30 parameters, I don't think you'd want to aggregate all FTS fields into a single parameter. That would likely produce a lot of false positives.

It's messy, but if you need to support FTS constrained to a given field, you're going to have to track them separately, and if you're using sprocs, that will mean multiple parameters. Your only other option would be dynamic (but still parameterized to avoid SQL injection issues) SQL.